# VideoJS 5 video player change hit box of volume and progress bar

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have added the `HTML5 VideoJS Player` on my page and i have a problem with the volume and progress bar. 
The `hitbox` (the space where you click) for both bars is very small and it works just if you click in the bar level.
I hope it is clear, else you can try out in the JsFiddle (I add in the comment) to change the loudness ord the progress.
**Edit 1:** It should work also if you click outside of the bar level and i would´nt change the height of the bar level.
 **Edit 2:** The hitbox of the mute button is small too.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/oa3d23pL/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can achive it for example in this way:

1. Increase `hitbox` height too fill whole control bar and make it transparent (still you will be able to click on them)
2. add additional DOM element to display current progress or volume (you can also use `:before`).

Here is a simple proof-of-concept: https://jsfiddle.net/oa3d23pL/1/

Comment: Perfectly, it works thank you. Dont get working for the volume bar :(. https://jsfiddle.net/oa3d23pL/2/

Comment: It is possible to do this also for the volume bar :) https://jsfiddle.net/oa3d23pL/3/